# TreeView Control in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I am using a asp .net tree view control whose "ShowCheckBoxes" property has been set to "All".  Now if the user checks the root node, i want all nodes under it to be "checked". I have looked at the event model, but i cannot find a event or a property that tells me if the checked node is a root or a child node.

How do i find if the selected node is a root or a child?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with javascript, look @

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128094224/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/03/25/73300.aspx)

or

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2008/06/17/treeview-automatically-check-all-childnode-checkboxes-on-checking-parentnode-checkbox-using-javascript.aspx

Sorry for the short answer...

:)

//W